# When to use which of Fujifilm X Camera's Film Simulation options?

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-xpro1, fujifilm-xe1

I've been using the Fuji X-E1 for several months now and I'm still quite confused on when to use the film simulations like Astia, Hi-Pro neg & Neg standard. In what particular scenario should I use which film in different situations? I know that it is a matter of taste & style on what film should one use, but what do other Fuji users use in what situations?

Comment: I had a similar question to this earlier. Maybe [How do I evaluate a camera's JPEG tone curve options when the manufacturer only provides flowery prose?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22966/how-do-i-evaluate-a-cameras-jpeg-tone-curve-options-when-the-manufacturer-only) will help a little bit?

Comment: There is no way one can answer this for you. I personally test all the modes and set it to the one that gives the most realistic color. I *never* change it after that but that is because of the style of photo I like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you desire the look they offer. Don't look to others as for when they use them. Try them out, see how they work. Use them in unconventional ways. Following a herd is boring.